# Code structure choice for a manufacturer-like function in Prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop

I am currently developing a website for an art gallery which sells artworks online. I need to develop some code to gather and display information about artists (bio, mail, email, dates of exhibition,...). I first tried to use the manufacturers function and to only adapt the translations, replacing "manufacturer" by "artist" but I soon realized that I was limited. I do not need to associate an artist with its address and I need additional information. The problem is I do not know what would be the best way to implement this, while keeping my code clean and make prestashop upgrades easy to do.

I think I will need to make new database tables, as follows (exhibition dates, not implemented yet):

```
CREATE TABLE `artist` (
  `id_artist` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `date_add` datetime NOT NULL,
  `date_upd` datetime NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_artist`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `artist_lang` (
  `id_artist` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_lang` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `short_description` text NOT NULL,
  `meta_title` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `meta_keywords` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `meta_description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_artist`,`id_lang`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Should I make this a module, or directly add an artist module and controllers in the core classes? If I do so, I will have to override the product class. Since I do not need the manufacturers, should I override the manufacturer class?

Comment: @tereško Thanks for the edit. Prestashop uses the MVC pattern but my question is not directly related to MVC even if my code structure should comply with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the same question on the [Prestashop forum](http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/181185-code-structure-choice-for-a-manufacturer-like-function-for-artists-in-art-shop/page__p__895409) and got good advice that I will summarize here if someone had the same problem.

There is no way around modifying core classes but override should be used as much as possible.

---

### Back-office functions

- Create the database table, as mentioned in the question.
- Create an `Artist` class in `overrides/classes` by copy-pasting the `ManufacturerCore` class and and substituting mentions of `manufacturer` by `artist` as well as specifying the additional fields as instance variables.
- Create an `ArtistController` class in `overrides/controllers` and substitute mentions of `manufacturer` by `artist`
- Override the `Product` class and add `id_artist` and `artist_name` as instance variables. Modify the following functions so that a product is linked with its artist: `__construct`, `getFields` and `getProducts`
- Create a `ArtistsAdmin` subclass of `AdminTab` in `admin/tabs` so that the back-office can be used to add new/edit artists
- Enable the tab in the back-office (employees -> tab -> add new)
- Modify `admin/ajax.php` so that the artists can be queries form the back-office
- Modify `ProductsAdmin` in `admin/tabs` so that the user can choose an artist when adding/editing a product
- Create a logo for the artists tab and copy it in `img/admin/artist.gif` and `img/admin/artists.gif`
- Handle the image folder in `config/defines.inc.php`:

  define('_ARTI_DIR_',    _PS_IMG_.'ar/');
  define('_PS_ARTI_IMG_DIR_',              _PS_IMG_DIR_.'ar/');
- Crate the `ar` folder in `img` and set write permissions for everyone

### Front-Office functions (not tested yet, might lack some info):

- Override Link with a function called `getDistributorLink` that models the `getSupplierLink`
- Override Tools to update the generateHtaccess function to include redirects for the artist that models the supplier redirects. I used 3 underscores (`___`), where the manufacturer uses 1 underscore (`_`) and supplier uses 2 underscores (`__`).
- Theme files (templates, css) to support the new core files.
- If you want to display the artist on the product page, you could also create a module that hooks extraRight, or one or more of the product page hooks.

Comment: You can create new classes directly in the `overrides/classes` directory without messing with the `/classes` directory at all. Just use the class name `Artist`. I haven't tried the same with controllers, but I would try it - much cleaner than adding files to the core directories in my opinion.

Comment: Yeah, I did this eventually. I edited my answer to reflect these changes. It works for controllers too. Thank you for the comment!

Comment: By the way, the same could be done with ProductAdmin and the artist admin tab by moving them into a module to keep the core clean.